# Maximize Chromium browser in playwright-rs

Tags: rust, chromium, playwright

I am trying to open a Chromium browser in fullscreen using playwright-rs.
I hoped I could do it with Chromium line switches, like this

```
let playwright = Playwright::initialize().await?;
playwright.prepare()?;
let browser_type = playwright.chromium();

let browser_args = [String::from("--start-maximized")];
let launcher = browser_type.launcher().args(&browser_args).headless(false);
let browser = launcher.launch().await?;
```

but it just ignores the args.

Any suggestions?